# Promise not getting called only on devices Ionic | Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm working with Angular & Ionic 6, all my functionality are working on emulators & browser but not working in Mobile devices.

In Component A

```
   addtrip() {
    this.dataService.addTrips(this.tripDetails).then(res => {
      if(res) {
        alert('res called');
        this.toastr.success('Trip Added Successfully');
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/home').then(res => console.log('Moved to home page'));
      }
    });
  }
```

In Service.ts

```
addTrips(trip) {
    alert('addTrips service called')
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      alert('addTrips promise called')
      this.db.list(`mcDrivers/${this.user.uid}/activeTrips`).update(trip.tripId, trip).then(res => {
        alert('addTrips promise resolved');
        resolve('Promise Resolved');
      }).catch(e => {
        reject(e);
        console.log(e);
      })
    });
  }
```

On the Mobile Devices, I get the following alert,

```
alert('clicked')
alert('service called')
alert('promise called')
```

After that nothing happens, I'm not getting `alert('success called')` or  `alert('error called')` alert messages. App just stays dead.

I'm dono what is wrong in here ?

Please help me, I'm stuck & unable to proceed further.

Comment: You don’t seem to resolve your promise anywhere.?

Comment: Where do i need to resolve the promise ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Add resolve to return Your promise data:
  async addTrips(trip) {
    alert('service called')

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      alert('promise called')
      this.db.list(`mcDrivers/${this.user.uid}/activeTrips`).push(trip).then(res => {
        alert('success called')
        this.toastr.success('Trip Added Successfully');
resolve();
      }).catch(e => {
        alert('error called')
        console.log(e);
reject();
      })
    });
  }
```

Comment: I've updated my question, still I'm getting the same issue

Comment: I've added the provide the Resolve in my service, still same issue

Comment: alert() function will stop your program propagation.So You should  remove it when You run your application.

Comment: I've just added for debug purpose

Comment: I thing your issue has been fixed.